# Request.JSON ending in onFailure when specific value is passed

Tags: javascript, php

I have a select list where when a given option is selected I send a request call to the server to return all items that are in that category. However for some reason when i pass the 2nd and the 4th values I my callback returns as onFailure. I was hoping I could get some pointers because it really doesn't make sense why the rest of the select options would work.

```
HTML
<select id="category" onChange="categorySelect()">
                <option value="0" selected> Category</option>
                <option value="Electronics">Electronics</option>
                <option value="Home_Goods">Home Goods</option>
                <option value="Kitchen">Kitchen</option>
                <option value="GiftCard">Gift Cards</option>
                <option value="Dining">Dining</option>
            </select>
JS
function categorySelect() {
    var category = $('category').getSelected()[0].getProperty('value');
    prizeCategoryRequest.setOptions({
        data : {
            'category' : category
        }
    }).send();

}

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

prizeCategoryRequest = new Request.JSON({
        method : 'post',
        async : true,
        url : 'prizePickFunctions.php',
        data : {
            'action' : 'prizeCategory',
            'category' : ''
        },
        onRequest : function() {
                console.log('Prize category requesting...');
        },
        onSuccess : function(response) {
            if (response.result == true) {
                console.log(response.html);
                $('prizePick').set('html', response.html);
            } else {
            //  $('PrizesDiv').set('html', response.errorMsg);
                alert('Error');
            }
        },
        onFailure : function() {
                alert('Error Page Not Found');
            }

    });

})

PHP
  $category = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('db', 'root', 'root');
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Select table before adding prizes
        $stmt = $dbh->query("Select * from prizes where category ='$category'");
 $prizes = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //echo count($prizes);
        if (count($prizes) == 0) {
            $returnVals['html'] = 'There are no prizes in this category';
        } else {
 foreach ($prizes as $entry)
            {

                $returnVals['html'] .= '<li><div id="prizeCategory">Category:' . $entry['category'] . '</div>';
                $returnVals['html'] .= '<div id="adminPrizeName">' . $entry['description'] . '</div>';
                $returnVals['html'] .= '<div id="description">' . $entry['prize'] . '</div>';
                 $returnVals['html'] .= '<button onclick="prizePicked(this,'.$entry['iPrizeID'].') value="' . $entry['iPrizeID'] . '">Select prize above</button>';
                $returnVals['html'] .= '</li>';
            }
}
 } catch (PDOException $e) {

        $returnVals['result'] = false;

    }

}

echo json_encode($returnVals);
```

Now this all works when I click on any of the options except electronics and kitchen. I have ran the sql code and I return about 25 rows so that isn't wrong. However when I change the `$returnVals['html'] = ""` instead of  `$returnVals['html'] .="";` I do get the last record from the database but my request fails when I try to bring back all items. Both of these options have about 30 records that return which is less than the other options. The category matches what is on my table because I have tested it and I do get back records. Is there any way to see why my response is failing?

**EDIT:**
I found the solution. As it turns out the failure is coming from a weird character in one of the $entry['']. Some of the records were added ad hoc in the database so the code i had wrote to catch special characters was never applied. I forgot about the Smart apostrophes that are being used now a days and it just so happens that both Kitchen and electronic categories had one of those characters.

Comment: The `onFailure` callback should pass in an `event` object. Have you tried inspecting that to see what went wrong? Or just hitting the php script directly?

Comment: No I gad not done that actually. I'll go ahead and give it a try.